# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up after suspend Lenovo Ideapad 5 Slim

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I can’t wake my laptop up after it goes into suspend.

OS:
Ubuntu 20.04

Hardware:
Lenovo Ideapad Slim 5
Ryzen 7 Octa Core 4700U -
(8 GB/512 GB SSD/Windows 10 Home)
14ARE05 Thin and Light Laptop

Comment: Looks like you mentioned the problem in the subject , but forgot to mention in the body , please [edit] your question to make it much more clear , as the body seems to be meaning less , add the problem you are facing to body too